# Backfround mode android oreo ionic

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to run android geolocalization in background, but now with background limitation **(api 26)** after a while my service is put in idle state and it doesn't return coordinates anymore. Is there any plugin updated to api 26 ?

I have tried to fix the plugin but Cordova return me a problem with `ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context,intent)`.

Is possible noone is has encountered this problem ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0#jobscheduler

Answer (score 0):

On [@mauron85's *free* fork of `cordova-plugin-background-geolocation`](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/), v3 is fixed to work with API 26 (Oreo)'s new background limitations (see [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/blob/master/CHANGES.md) for details), however v3 is currently in alpha.

To give it a try, install the alpha version of the plugin to your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation@alpha
```

Comment: I tried to use it but using startForegorundService foregound service doesn't work. It is not lauched